# Any possible way to upload wordpress theme download from httrack?

Tags: wordpress, upload, wordpress-theming

Am new to wordpress. I have downloaded wordpress theme through httrack. Got html files. If I upload those folders in wordpress theme whether it will work or any other way for uploading theme in wordpress?

Answer (score 2):

The truth is you can't download a valid wordpress site using HTTrack.
Reason is... HTTracks cannot download server-side scripts (php) and database.
A valid wordpress site cannot work without the two i.e (PHP Files and Databases).

Answer (score 0):

httrack only provides you the HTML and assets (js,css) files. Direct upload will not work in WordPress as there are predefined structure for a theme.

For examples, you need to create functions.php, style.css (add theme details) etc..

For more info please go to official theme development tutorial:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development